# Application.Exit() throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified...'

Tags: shutdown

(Visual Studio 2022-Community -- .Net 5 -- Windows 10)

I have been fighting an issue for days and have finally given up and have to ask the "smart people" for help.

I'm in Visual Studio (2022-Community) debugging my application.  When I click on the "close button" I close Internet connection, database connections, then exit the app.  In my log file I see "=== Application closed ===" in the log so it's making it to the end of the main TRY - CATCH block.  It then steps out to a "DoEvents()" (which I added just because I couldn't find anything else wrong and though that maybe some resource was waiting).

It even executes the `Application.Exit()` and moves to the curly-bracket after it:

```
                applog.Info("=== Application closed ===");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strError = $"Application Error{Environment.NewLine}{ex.ToString()}";
            applog.Error(strError);
            MessageBox.Show(strError, "Application Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        Application.DoEvents();
        Application.Exit();
        
    }     //-  <--- Error is happening HERE
}
```

}

...then throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion() in /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ThrowHelper.cs:line 361
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare() in /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs:line 1109
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPool.ReclaimLeakedConnections() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionPool.cs:line 168
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPool.Clear() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionPool.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.ReleasePool(SqliteConnectionPool pool, Boolean clearing) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionFactory.cs:line 129
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPoolGroup.Clear() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionPoolGroup.cs:line 59
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.ClearPools() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionFactory.cs:line 146
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.<.ctor>b__7_1(Object _, EventArgs _) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteConnectionFactory.cs:line 31
   at System.AppContext.OnProcessExit() in /_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/AppContext.cs:line 77
```

I've closed out the database connections.  I even "disposed" them to make sure they were gone.

I know that the "Collection was modified..." exception means that you can't change a collection you are iterating through, but at this point my code isn't iterating through anything.

I'd appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: I will also add that when I run the EXE from the "Debug" directory, It doesn't throw an Exception to the user, but I see it in the Windows Application Log.

Comment: Does "Application.Exit()" TERMINATE a program right at that spot in execution?  I ask because I put an "Application.Exit();" right before the code that starts to load my splash screen...and then stepped through the "Application.Exit()" magic that happens.  When it got back to my main form...it stepped PAST the Application.Exit() and started loading my Splash Screen...which crashed because all forms, message pumps, ext. were terminated.  I would have expected that code after Application.Exit() would just be "unreachable".